# How can I make lxml save two pages to the pages so it can be read by the tree?

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I'm parsing information of a top 100 list from a site that keeps track of crypto coin prices of the top 1000 coins or something like that using xlml. How can I add the second page to my tree just in case one of my top 100, I'm tracking, falls below the top 100 and ends up on page two? Link to my code: https://github.com/cbat971/CoinScraping/blob/master/WebCrawl.py

I've tried making a "page2" variable, adding "," to page variable, adding a "+" to page variable.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import datetime
import time

page = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/', 'https://coinmarketcap.com/2')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
```

If all 100 coins I have on the list are on page one, there is no problem. But as soon as one gets pushed to page two, there is an error and no coins after that get processed through the `for` statement at the end.

Comment: `get()` can get only one page. You have to do it in loop and you have to read every page separatelly, parse it separatelly, get values from HTML separatelly, and add results to the same list or dictionary. So finally you will have list/dictionary with all results.

Comment: you could try to read every page separatelly `page1 = request.get()` , `page2 = request.get()` and concatenate `page1.content + page2.content` to create one string with both HTML but I'm not sure if `lxml` can parse string which has two `<html>` and two `<body>`. Every page has only one `<html>` and one `<body>` and two pages in one string can be treated as error. Or it can parse only first page and skip other pages in string.

Answer (score 1):

You could try concatenate both HTML using

```
page1.content + page2.content
```

but it will not works because `lxml` expects only one `<html>` and one `<body>` and it will parse only first page and skip other pages.

Run code and you get only one `

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page1 = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/')
page2 = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/2')

tree = html.fromstring(page1.content + page2.content)

print(tree.cssselect('body'))
```

---

You have to process every page separatelly - read it, parse it and get values from HTML - and add results to one list/dictionary

This code gives two `<body>`

```
from lxml import html
import requests

for url in ('https://coinmarketcap.com/', 'https://coinmarketcap.com/2'):
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    print(tree.cssselect('body'))
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
from lxml import html
import requests

data = {
    'BTC': 'id-bitcoin',
    'TRX': 'id-tron',
    # ...
    'HC': 'id-hypercash',
    'XZC': 'id-zcoin',
}    

all_results = {}

for url in ('https://coinmarketcap.com/', 'https://coinmarketcap.com/2'):
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

    print(tree.cssselect('body'))

    for key, val in data.items():

        result = tree.xpath('//*[@id="' + val + '"]/td[4]/a/text()')

        print(key, result)

        if result:
            all_results[key] = result[0]

print('---')
print(all_results)
```

Result:

```
[<Element body at 0x7f6ba576cd68>]
BTC ['$6144.33']
TRX ['$0.023593']
HC []
XZC []
[<Element body at 0x7f6ba57fb4f8>]
BTC []
TRX []
HC ['$1.05']
XZC ['$6.25']
---
{'BTC': '$6144.33', 'TRX': '$0.023593', 'HC': '$1.05', 'XZC': '$6.25'}
```